# What service is better to speed up website Cloudflare or AWS Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

Hi I have a Drupal website with images in each news articles it's a news website.

I'm debating whether to use Cloudflare or AWS Cloudfront..

Can the experts here advise me which service is better to speed up my site especially for mobile visitors?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that in general CloudFlare and Amazon AWS will both give excellent results and will be similar if you are only comparing how they reduce latency by serving static content from a data centre closest to your site visitors.

CloudFlare's paid plans include [Polish](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-polish-automatic-image-optimizati/) and [Mirage (beta)](https://www.cloudflare.com/mirage/) which both claim to improve mobile performance by optimising images and customising page delivery based on device specifics and network speed.

If mobile performance is a priority for you, an option you could consider is the free CloudFlare plan + hosting on a server with [Google's PageSpeed module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/). In my experience, PageSpeed gives excellent results, it's low maintenance, and included in [its filters](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/config_filters) are options like **resize_mobile_images** which does just what it says.

Good luck!

Comment: Dear David so Google pagespeed module works with Cloudflare? Kindly advise Thanks!

Comment: Hi @user3236765, Google pagespeed and Cloudflare work well together for me with the caching configuration I have on our sites. You can can check by setting a site to use both, then open a page with images then use Chrome web inspector > network > img > any image > headers > response headers > cf-cache-status. What you want to see for cf-cache-status is Hit. And if details for any of the static resources on the page change, the version number that pagespeed automatically adds to the path of the optimised resource means that Cloudflare will automatically pick up the new file.

Comment: The issue also is that I'm using Drupal 6 dynamically

Comment: Hi @user3236765, could you clarify what you mean by using Drupal 'dynamically' ?

Comment: Hi Drupal creates pages on the fly I think. What are you cache settings for apache/google pagespeed and cloudflare if you don't mind my asking? Thanks!

Comment: hi google pagespeed seems to change the file name of every image loaded wouldn't that make Cloudflare go crazy caching files with different names per user?

Comment: Hi @user3236765, I'm using the default settings for PageSpeed, CloudFlare my caching level is typically standard with a 1 month expiration.  Drupal won't complicate anything for you,  I'm using PageSpeed + CloudFlare on a number of Joomla sites, one is www.panchroma.ca if you want to inspect what happens to images. It's true PageSpeed changes file names, though not a different version for ever visitor. Taking a jpg image as an example it will create an optimized jpg version (for browsers which don't understand webp) and an optimized webp version. All visitors are served one of the two versions

Comment: Hi David is there any way for mod_pagespeed to stop changing names of the .jpg files? Any settings in pagespeed.conf?

Comment: > is there any way for mod_pagespeed to stop changing names of the .jpg files?  ... not that I know of @user3236765, and I can't picture how mod_pagespeed could work if it didn't change file names

Comment: Hi David another question does minify css and js work with Cloudflare?

Comment: Yes, css and js magnification will work. I you have mod_pagespeed configured to do this and then there's no advantage to having CloudFlare set to minify them as well. It doesn't break anything if you tried to minify a second time, you just wouldn't get any benefit.

Comment: Hi David thanks how do you use Modpagespeed setting to minify css?

Comment: Hi @user3236765, minify css is on by default in mod_pagespeed. For more about rewrite_css see https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-css-rewrite
 and for more info about which filters are enabled by default see the table part way down https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/config_filters .

Comment: Thanks David have you tried minify html via Cloudflare?

Comment: Yes, I have and I don't remember ever having any complications

Comment: Hey David many thanks for the quick responses. I ran modpagespeed and Cloudflare as you suggested. The results are good! However, I had to disable ModPagespeedDisableFilters defer_javascript as my Google Adsense earnings crashed for last 2 days.. Any way to get around this issue? I cannot confirm if crash in adsense earnings is due to deferjavascript setting. Any comments? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend AWS CloudFront.

To deliver content to end users with lower latency, Amazon CloudFront uses a global network of edge locations for content delivery. Amazon CloudFront edge locations are located in:

**United States**

Ashburn, VA (3)
Atlanta, GA
Chicago, IL
Dallas/Fort Worth, TX (2)
Hayward, CA
Jacksonville, FL
Los Angeles, CA (2)
Miami, FL
New York, NY (3)
Newark, NJ
Palo Alto, CA
San Jose, CA
Seattle, WA
South Bend, IN
St. Louis, MO

**Europe**
Amsterdam, The Netherlands (2)
Dublin, Ireland
Frankfurt, Germany (3)
London, England (3)
Madrid, Spain
Marseille, France
Milan, Italy
Paris, France (2)
Stockholm, Sweden
Warsaw, Poland

**Asia**

Chennai, India
Hong Kong (2)
Mumbai, India
Manila, the Philippines
New Delhi, India
Osaka, Japan
Seoul, Korea (3)
Singapore (2)
Taipei, Taiwan
Tokyo, Japan (2)

**Australia**

Melbourne, Australia
Sydney, Australia

**South America**

São Paulo, Brazil
Rio de Janeiro, Brazil

Read more about [Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)

Comment: Downvoted because you provide no motivation for why you "highly recommend" CloudFront, besides boasting a "global network of edge locations"  -- which CloudFlare also has. So this doesn't help in answering the question.